# Eclipse JDT LS & Gradle - Resource Exception "Invalid project description"

Tags: gradle, vim-plugin, eclipse-jdt, neovim

#### Summary

I've been trying to get [Eclipse's JDT LS](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls) (JLS) working with [vim-lsp](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp) (in Neovim), but have been unsuccessful in synchronising the JLS with a Gradle project. I am, unfortunately, constrained to Windows.

#### The Problem

Using [this configuration](https://github.com/Priddles/nvim-lsp-with-jdt) (commit [#d1c7a25](https://github.com/Priddles/nvim-lsp-with-jdt/tree/d1c7a254342bf8ab007dad67e770f2184168ec0f) at the time of posting), I cannot synchronise the JLS with a Gradle project *"due to an error configuring Eclipse"* because of an *"invalid project description"* (see [log](https://github.com/Priddles/nvim-lsp-with-jdt/blob/master/Invalid-project-description.pretty.log)).

Trawling through Google and the GitHub issues of both the JLS and vim-lsp plugin has gotten me nowhere.

#### Remarks

I feel like it's most likely an issue with my configuration. If anyone has got this working with other LSP plugins aside from [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) (such as [CoC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) or [LanguageClient](https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim)) those setups are also welcome, but vim-lsp is preferred.

**To reiterate, and just in case:**

- Windows 10 Pro (v1803 build 17134.407)
- Neovim (v0.3.1) with plugin [vim-lsp](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp)
- Gradle wrapper (v4.10.2)
- Eclipse [JDT LS](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls) (v0.28.0 build 201811140630) [[.tar.gz](http://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/snapshots/jdt-language-server-0.28.0-201811140630.tar.gz)]
- using [this configuration](https://github.com/Priddles/nvim-lsp-with-jdt) (originally [#d1c7a25](https://github.com/Priddles/nvim-lsp-with-jdt/tree/d1c7a254342bf8ab007dad67e770f2184168ec0f))

*Thanks!*

Comment: 'Invalid project description' means either the project name is not valid for the platform or the project URI is invalid. Since this is Windows there are quite a few things that can make a project name invalid.

Comment: @greg-449 The JLS creates a project named `jdt.ls-java-project` and using Eclipse IDE, I can both create a project with the same name in a fresh workspace and load the workspace created by the JLS.

There is a `rootUri` in the logs (which I believe is part of the LSP) which points to the root directory of the repository. This URI is formatted correctly, but setting the `rootUri` to the JLS workspace just seemed to confuse it.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

The workspace directory for the JLS (specified by the command line argument `-data`) can't be nested under the project's own directory.

**bashes head on desk**

Comment: Thank you! This really should be documented. 

Comment: March 2023, and same weird undocumented requirements of the data dir are still in place. *repeatedly bashes head on desk*.